# Which is the simplest way to aggregate rows (sum) in python under certain columns conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, tidy

I have try using aggregate and group by functions without success, the thing is like this df:

```
df:
index   var1   var2   col1   col2
1        1      10     15     23
2        1       1     34     32
2        2       1     12     32
2        1       2     14     16
2        2       2      4     16
3        1       3     65     12
3        2       3      5     12
```

df.function:

```
index   var2   col1   col2
1        10     15     23
2         1     46     32
2         2     18     16
3         3     70     12
```

Notice, the sum it's done by the col1 and not the col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick here is using agg to apply a different aggregate function to col1 and col2. You can do this using a dictionary with keys as the column names. I used max for col2 but could be first or last or whatever, depends what you want.

`df.groupby(['index', 'var2']).agg({'col1':'sum', 'col2':'max'})`

Output:

```
            col1  col2
index var2            
1     10      15    23
2     1       46    32
      2       18    16
3     3       70    12
```